# Decision tree true or false operators vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if someone could help with the decision tree logic. Currently it seems to pass all true false statements and is trapped by the last else statement. It would be good for my learning to understand where the failure in the logic is.

Cheers,
B.

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

      Dim Name As Boolean = False
      Dim fileUp As Boolean = False
      Dim fileSize As Boolean = False
      Dim fileCheck As Boolean = False
      Dim FileOK As Boolean = False
      Dim fileTypeCheck As String = String.Empty
      Dim fileSizeCheck As Integer

      If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
                     Name = False
      Else 
                     Name = True
      End If

      If FileUploadControl.HasFile Then
                     fileUp = True
      End If

      fileSizeCheck = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength
      If fileSizeCheck < 56320 Then
                     fileSize = True
      End If

      fileTypeCheck = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType
      If fileTypeCheck = "text/plain" Then
                     fileCheck = True
      End If

      If Name = false
                     StatusLabel.Text = "Update Status: Please Enter Your Name Logon"

      ElseIf Name = True And fileUp = False
                     StatusLabel.Text = "Update Status: Please Enter List to be uploaded"

      ElseIf Name = False And fileUp = False
                     StatusLabel.Text = "Update Status: Update Status: Please Enter Your Name and List to be uploaded"

      ElseIf Name = True And fileUp = True And fileSize = False
                     StatusLabel.Text = "Update Status: Only text files under 55kb can be accepted"

      ElseIf Name = True And fileUp = True And fileSize = True And fileCheck = False
                     StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Cannot Accept File. Only text files are accepted"

      ElseIf Name = True And fileUp = True And fileSize = True And fileCheck = True
      fileOk = True
      End IF


      If fileOK Then
           Try        
                Dim objFSO, objFolder
                objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                objFolder = "D:\PSTMailBoxReports\uploads\" & TextBox1.Text & "-" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-fff")
                If objFSO.FolderExists(objFolder) = True Then
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: folder exists"
                ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists(objFolder) <> True Then
                    objFSO.CreateFolder(objFolder)
                    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(objFolder.ToString)
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Entering New Upload folder please wait"
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Creating Upload folder " & objFolder & ", Please now wait"
                    Dim physicalFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString
                    Dim fileName As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString
                    Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName)
                    FileUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder, fileName + extension))
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!"
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Else
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Error Please Retry "
        End If
    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Give us a sample input and a sample output. You have to order you if statements logically.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and ditch the FileSystemObject.  Use the built in .Net classes in `System.IO` instead.  They are much faster and if this code is to be run on a web server, be aware that many times the scripting object is not installed for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hint not a complete solution, since you did not show a sample of your input.

You need to ensure that all cases are taken care of (see possible values below. Given 4 binary variables, you get 2x2x2x2 cases. You can use this table to build the correct IF/ELSE structure.

```
Name    FileUp  FileSize FileCheck
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
FALSE   FALSE   TRUE     FALSE
FALSE   FALSE   TRUE     TRUE
FALSE   TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
FALSE   TRUE    FALSE    TRUE
FALSE   TRUE    TRUE     FALSE
FALSE   TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
TRUE    FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
TRUE    FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
TRUE    FALSE   TRUE     FALSE
TRUE    FALSE   TRUE     TRUE
TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    TRUE
TRUE    TRUE    TRUE     FALSE
TRUE    TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
```

In your code, you start by testing:

```
IF Name=False
```

then after few tests, you do:

```
ElseIf Name = False And fileUp = False
```

This last test will never execute when (name=false) because the action taken at the first if will be executed first and the if will terminated.

In other words, the above 2 lines are not mutually exclusive.

So you need to be careful in using ELSEIF, so that each test is mutually execlusive with the other tests.

I also would recommend that you use debugging to see how the conditions are tested.

Comment: I'l try the logic suggested shortly. It's to upload a text file, from the front end web page. I am trying to add conditional logic to preform checks prior to saving the file.